# Renameing a bunch of quicktimes in applescript

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a bunch of files in a folder named something like this:

123456_this_is_a_fun_test_v01.mov

685954_this_more_is_a_fun_test_v01_clean.mov

They all have a 6 digit number in the beginning and a version number somewhere. What i need to do is remove the version number and move the first 6 digits til the end, before the extension name, like this:

this_is_a_fun_test_123456.mov

this_more_is_a_fun_test_clean_685954.mov

Been trying some stuff out in automator and some simple Applescripting, but without any luck. My scripting skills are not good, I'm only at "Hobby" level. Anyone got some advice?

```
tell application "Finder"
--grab the selected files and put them into a variable
set F to selection


 end tell
-- This will be the character used to rejoin pieces
-- of the filename after breaking them apart
set the text item delimiters to "_"

 repeat with g in F -- Loop through the file list

-- Get the filename
tell application "System Events" to get name of g

-- Eliminate the version number component of the filename
set r to do shell script ¬
    "echo " & quoted form of result & ¬
    " | egrep -o '[^_\\.]+'" & ¬
    " | egrep -iv 'v\\d+'"

-- Assemble the other components in the new order
get {paragraphs 2 thru -2, paragraph 1} of r
get (result as text) & ".mov"

-- Rename the file to the new name
tell application "System Events" to set name of g to result

end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added comments to this AppleScript, which explain what each part of the script does.  As it stands, it's designed to run from inside *Script Editor*, but it could easily be tweaked to be part of an *Automator* workflow.

Copy-n-paste the script into *Script Editor*.  Replace */Path/To/Folder* with the path to the folder in which your *.mov* files are located (keep the quotes).  Use the full path, i.e. */Users/CK/Movies* and not *~/Movies*.  Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to compile the script, and check for pre-run syntax errors, and the like.  When the fonts change and the script looks all pretty-printed, then hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to execute it.

```
    tell application "System Events" to get the files in folder ¬
        "/Path/To/Folder" whose name extension is "mov"

    set F to the result -- The list of .mov files that need renaming

    -- This will be the character used to rejoin pieces
    -- of the filename after breaking them apart
    set the text item delimiters to "_"

    repeat with g in F -- Loop through the file list

        -- Get the filename
        tell application "System Events" to get name of g

        -- Eliminate the version number component of the filename
        set r to do shell script ¬
            "echo " & quoted form of result & ¬
            " | egrep -o '[^_\\.]+'" & ¬
            " | egrep -iv 'v\\d+'"

        -- Assemble the other components in the new order
        get {paragraphs 2 thru -2, paragraph 1} of r
        get (result as text) & ".mov"

        -- Rename the file to the new name
        tell application "System Events" to set name of g to result

    end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks the script works like a charm...
Just found out that the folder might get updated with new files, so i thought that i would change it into a "service" instead. I tried to modify your script, and it seams like it works on one file, but when multiple are selected it has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of google Fu and a lot of looking at your code i got it to work on selected files. Thanks for the help

```
tell application "Finder"
set F to selection
end tell


set the text item delimiters to "_"

repeat with g in F -- Loop through the file list

-- Get the filename
tell application "Finder" to get name of g

-- Eliminate the version number component of the filename
set r to do shell script ¬
    "echo " & quoted form of result & ¬
    " | egrep -o '[^_\\.]+'" & ¬
    " | egrep -iv 'v\\d+'"

-- Assemble the other components in the new order
get {paragraphs 2 thru -2, paragraph 1} of r
get (result as text) & ".mov"

-- Rename the file to the new name
tell application "Finder" to set name of g to result

end repeat

tell application "System Events"
activate
display dialog "Selected files have been renamed!"
end tell
```